# Vertically aligning a stretched flex without using paddings and margin

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm using a flexbox with align-items-stretch as I needed the borders to be reaching on both top and bottom. Not allowing the usage of margins and paddings, how can I come about vertically aligning the text within flex without facing any property conflict?

I've tried using the align-items-stretch and within the `ul li` added a `align-middle` class but it doesn't seem to do anything seeing that the property clashes.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse align-items-stretch" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">Home</li>
        <li class="nav-item">About Us</li>
        <li class="nav-item ">Services</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This current code does the trick of stretching my borders but the text within the flexbox could not be centralized.

Comment: You can add a box shadow for showing the border around the nav items as like: .navbar-nav li { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px red;  }

Comment: use `li.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}`

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the `line-height` with value the same the height of the `.nav-item`?

Example:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-item {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse align-items-stretch" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">Home</li>
        <li class="nav-item">About Us</li>
        <li class="nav-item ">Services</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/jutvsw26/

For more detailed answer could you please add some CSS that you're currently using.